# Is there any way to redirect to website according to change of iframe url

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

can we change the windows location according to iframe url. if there is a change of url inside iframe could we redirect to other page?

note: iframe urls would be 3 to 4.

Comment: php doesn't know any type of frame ... so flag your question again

Comment: Please edit your question for clarity, as it stands its not at all clear what you are asking